# How To Make Splash Screen Sizes For iPad Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, splash-screen

I am trying to create `splash screen` for `iPhone` and `iPad` by programmatically. Here below I have added my code which i am using and output screen Into `iPad2` simulators showing half screen. I need to make full screen size for iPad all devices.

My Code Below:

```
 // The device is an iPad and iPad mini running iOS 3.2 or later.
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 1024) {

            // iPad, iPad 2, iPad Mini
            splashImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768,result.height);
            [splashImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default-Portrait.png" ]];
            activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(145, 240, 30, 30);
        }
        if(result.height == 2048) {

            // iPad Air, iPad Mini Retina
            splashImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1536,result.height);
            [splashImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default-Portrait.png" ]];
            activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(145, 240, 30, 30);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly how it is supposed to run unless it is a universal App. If it is iPhone only App, it will run like this (Like iPhone 4s & 4 inside your iPad).

Answer (score 0):

IPAD SPLASH

```
 iPadImage-Appname-Portrait.png * 768w x 1004h (with status bar)
 iPadImage-Appname-Portrait@2x.png * 1536w x 2008h (with status bar)
 iPadImage-Appname-Landscape.png ** 1024w x 748h (with status bar)
 iPadImage-Appname-Landscape@2x.png ** 2048w x 1496h (with status bar)

 iPadImage-Appname-Portrait.png * 768w x 1024h (without status bar)
 iPadImage-Appname-Portrait@2x.png * 1536w x 2048h (without status bar)
 iPadImage-Appname-Landscape.png ** 1024w x 768h (without status bar)
 iPadImage-Appname-Landscape@2x.png ** 2048w x 1536h (without status bar)
```

Comment: I am using same size but not working@Reshmi Majumder

Comment: did you set it in info.plist ?